# Huge difference between question asked time and last seen

Tags: discussion, bug

I don't know whether this question is asked before or not. If it's already there, please pardon.

I recently saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180278/search-json-object-with-objective-c#28180520) in Stack Overflow. In that there where a lot of comments seeking the clarification about the question, but OP didn't responded to any of them. So due to curiosity I checked his profile for checking the last seen time, it was something like:

[image: Last Seen]

But in question page it shows:

[image: Asked Time]

So my question is why Stack Overflow shows two different amount of time in both cases 1 Hour and 2 Hour ? Why such a huge difference ? (I saw similar behavior many times, but ignored) Is that a bug or status by design ?

Answer (score 1):

We'll have to assume that you viewed those both sometime between 23:09 and 23:24. Anytime past 23:09, they would have been seen 2 hours ago. The question, though, isn't 2 hours old until the 23:24 mark hits.

Comment: Rounding is such fun. However you do it, it's always "wrong".

Comment: Right, but how come the user wasn't "seen" when he posted his question? Ghostwriting?